# Joystick Buttons problem since update 2.78

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

im making a game on 2.77a, my menus are working correctly.
I updated blender to 2.78, but my joystick buttons are not detected at all.
The Joystick movement still work, but blender is unable to detect any pressed buttons from my gamepad.
I previously made this simple, with logic bricks, but i tried to create a new logic brick, with exact same parameters as before, but nothing work.
I repair the installation but this didnt solve my problem.
Maybe this build of blender have some issues?

Comment: If blender was working before and now is not then it must be some kind of bug. Please report it using the appropriate channels: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar with my pythonscript i created for joystick inputs. It seems like Blender 2.8 changed the input a little bit. All buttons do have other indecies now, so i think you should remap them all, maybe this helps.

Comment: So the index of the buttons is changed? I will try this soon